# Remapping VMS keys

Tags: ssh, openvms

I sometimes must use a particular SSH client to access a VMS node.  This program has the peculiar property that when one presses the RETURN key, it issues a CTRL-J to the VAX session, making it difficult do much.

In VMS 5.5-2, is it possible to remap a CTRL-J as a CTRL-M in an incoming SSH session?

Comment: I just noticed that the guilty SSH client has been updated.  The previous almost-workaround (Option-J) doesn't work any more but Option-Return is now a perfect workaround, although not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say if you are using a Unix or Windows client, but I am assuming Unix.  I believe the Windows client has a way to change this, but I'm not certain and it's been a long time since I needed to use putty.

As for remapping, no, there is no trivial way to do this.  VMS has a way to define what is used for backspace, but not for CR, that I can find online or in my memory.

What happens if you press control-M?  Does it send a ^J or ^M?  What happens if you press ^J then?  Is there any chance you can run a Xwindows command-line shell (Xterm or the like) and display it locally?  That would use X11 key mappings, which should be sane.

Comment: It's actually a Java-based client downloaded via a web page.  I've tried lots of keys and combinations but nothing seems to produce the equivalent.  I can use Option-J with success sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

5.5-2??  Granted, we *do* have our MicroVAX 3400s, but they're sitting turned off in a corner of a storeroom.  We stopped using them about 12 years ago and they had VMS 5.5-2 on them but that wasn't the most recent version even then.

Why can't you use PuTTy or some other client?

(I guess this should be a comment, but since this is a VMS question, I'm not expecting a lot of activity...)

Comment: I don't have a choice about the client.

Comment: We've estimated that it would cost about a million dollars to upgrade to a later version of VMS due to heavy dependence on custom device drivers.  And much more than that to move their functionality to another platform.  And we're in the (long) process of doing that...